# IE 9 issue and bootstrap... Need attention

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am buildong a website using bootstrap and facing quite different issue. Webpage has perfect view in chrome/firefox etc but IE i am facing different issue.

IE: http://www.waqastech.com/img/IE.png

Firefox: http://www.waqastech.com/img/firefox.png

Comment: Have you checked you're using a valid `DOCTYPE` ? We currently don't have enough informations to find your problem.

Comment: Does you markup validate?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you're not using `<section>...</section>` tags If you're using section,it doesn't work in ie 9 and below. I had this issue 2 days ago and when I changed my `<section>...</section>` tags to `<div>...</div>` tags, It worked perfectly.

Comment: While that may be true, you can get them to work by including the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) script in your `head` section before any other scripts. In addition, I believe bootstrap comes out of the box with some shims (shivs). Check out the bootstrap tutorial pages (this was true as of Bootstrap v2.3.2).